# Handling print-screen globally in Windows by a .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I make my C# application the default "Print Screen" handler in Windows?

I wrote a screen capturing utility and I want to, ideally, have it replace the default print-screen handler, or otherwise have a unique key combination that would trigger it.

I know how to do it in C++ using global hooks, etc., but it's not clear to me how this can be done in .Net. Also, if there's a way of doing it without using a memory resident application that would be super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using a WM_KEYBOARD_LL hook to capture the PrintScreen key, there is no reason you can't do this in C#.  It's one  of the few global hooks that can be used in managed code because it doesn't require a DLL to be injected into every target process.  Instead the context will switch back to the originating application for processing.

Adam's blog has a great post on how to setup such a hook in C#: http://www.seesharpdot.net/?tag=wh_keyboard_ll

Comment: I'll try it. But it does mean my program has to be running in order to capture the key-down, right?

Comment: @Assaf, yes, your programm will need to be running.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (OpenSource, free) with the following script?

This script was taken from the newsgroup of [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), it will map the printscreen to use IrfanView. You can use it to trigger your program.

```
~printscreen::
ifexist,%screenshot1%\irfanview.exe
    {
    run, "%screenshot1%\irfanview.exe" "/capture=0 /convert=%screenshots%\%A_now%_screenshot.jpg"
   sleep,500
   run,%screenshots%  ;open folder
   return
    }
return


~!printscreen::       ;copy only active window
ifexist,%screenshot1%\irfanview.exe
    {
```

Comment: A good suggestion. I do want to figure out how to do this in code before I insert a 3rd party dependency into my installer. But I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: AutoHotKey is really a standalone application which I cannot customize and package as part of my application easily. It's also roughly 2MB in size. As a generic shortcut tool it's great, but it's not a shortcut plugin for existing applications.